# Edit Auto Sum Conditioning Statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Need help editing totals when something is sold, it should subtract from totals.
[image]
[http://i.imgur.com/9G8oTPU.png](https://i.imgur.com/9G8oTPU.png)

To Calculate #1, the calculation should be B2-B1 (since it is sold and in red), #2 would be C2-C1 (since it is sold and in red), #3 should be E2-E1 (since E1 is sold and in red), #4 should be F1 plus any anthers in the same column that are highlighted in red, and #5 should be G1 plus any others that are sold and highlighted in red.

Comment: what formula do you have already, what have you already tried? In which cells exactly you want to have the formula?

Comment: @MátéJuhász I have it on AutoSum and thought it would subtract automatically.

Comment: please add also desired output, it's still not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MátéJuhász desired output would be for the first Total, $1, second total, $50, third total, $50, and fourth, $49

Comment: There are five totals and you only mention four in your comments, also those aren't clear how they're calculated... Please edit your question and explain where and what should be calculated. If you edit your post it will be moved again to the top of the list and you'll have the chance that somebody else will also read it, not only me.

Comment: @MátéJuhász fixed.